# Event or command to know everytime an item is selected from Checkedlistbox using mvvm,wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism-4

Iam using MVVM with WPF...I have a checkedlistbox with some items....everytime one item is checked, I want that item to be used in Viewmodel....Is there a property or command or event so that I can use it to know the checkeditem...

Here is my xaml...

```
   <ListBox Grid.Row="9" Height="49" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,30,0,0"      Name="aasdasd" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="205" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding userlist}" Grid.Column="1">
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Name="chkuser" Content="{Binding Path=useritem}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the items in `userList` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, your view model could subscribe to the [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event for every item in the list (making sure that it either uses [weak events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) or properly unsubscribes the event) and observer when the `IsChecked` property is changed to `true`.

Alternatively, you could use an event trigger on the [`Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked.aspx) event to execute a command in your view model.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding to the `IsChecked` on your model, so your viewModel can simply subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event for that item, and perform whatever action you want whenever that property changes

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    userList.CollectionChanged += userList_CollectionChanged;
}

void userList_CollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
        foreach(MyItem item in e.NewItems)
            item.PropertyChanged += MyItem_PropertyChanged;

    if (e.OldItems != null)
        foreach(MyItem item in e.OldItems)
            item.PropertyChanged -= MyItem_PropertyChanged;
}

void MyItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsChecked")
    {
        // Do whatever here
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on the location and lifetime of "userList" and its items, do you think it would make sense to subscribe to the CollectionChanged and PropertyChanged events using the WeakEvent pattern? Unless of course, MyViewModel runs some sort of clean-up code that unsubscribes. As I understand it, if the lifetime of the objects in userList is longer than the lifetime of "MyViewModel", then it will leak because the view model can't finalize. Please correct me if I'm wrong.